# No intValue on Swift 3 String?

Tags: macos, type-conversion, swift3

Does anybody know why you have to cast to `NSString` in order to get an `intValue` in Swift 3? Why doesn't the Swift `String` type have an `intValue`? I'm sure there's a reason, but I haven't been able to find an answer. Does it have anything to do with hardware architecture and Swift running on multiple platforms? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Int has a String initializer since Swift 2

Comment: You can extend String to add such properties if you would like to

Comment: `extension String { var intValue: Int { return Int(self) ?? 0 } }`

Comment: Thanks! That will really clean up my code not having to cast to NSString. Do you know why they chose to leave intValue, floatValue etc out of String in Swift?

Comment: I think it was just a matter of design. They preferred to add the String initializer to Int, Double, etc.

Comment: I see, please add your extension example as an answer so a can accept and give due credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend String to add such property as follow:

```
extension String { 
    var intValue: Int { 
        return Int(self) ?? 0 
    }
}
```